# SherlockActivity menu item doesn't fire with AndroidAnnotations @Click

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-annotations

I have this Activity that extends the SherlockFragmentActivity.
I also use AndroidAnnotations 3 and i used the @Click feature in another Activity (it works).

This is the working onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This is the onClickAction never fired

```
@Click
public void logoutButton() {
    Log.i("debug", "ok, i'm here");
}
```

This is the related res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:title="logout"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

As i said, when i touch the logoutButton it doesn't fire the event (or it doesn't catch it).
Any idea? There's something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, dear: it's @OptionsItem for ActionBar items, not @Click.

That's all.